# React Native - Picker Item show data in another picker

Tags: react-native, picker

When I pick one picker.item in Province, City will be showing the datas from Province.
Help me to solve this and here is my code :

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
                dataProvince: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                selProvince: '',
                dataVillage: ['D', 'E', 'H'],
                selVillage: '',
}

 <Text style={Styles.overviewTitle}>Province</Text>
                    <Picker note 
                                mode="dropdown"
                                style={Styles.textInput}
                                selectedValue={this.state.selProvince}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue)=>this.setState({selProvince: itemValue})}
                        >
                            {this.state.dataProvince.map((data, key) =>
                                <Picker.Item key={key} label={data.label} value={data.value} />
                            )}
                    </Picker>

 <Picker note 
                                mode="dropdown"
                                style={Styles.textInput}
                                selectedValue={this.state.selCity}
                                onValueChange={(itemValue)=>this.setState({selCity: itemValue})}
                        >
                            {this.state.dataCity.map((data, key) =>
                                <Picker.Item key={key} label={data.label} value={data.value} />
                            )}
                        </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you change the province you are already updating state value for selProvince. you just need a json object lets call it provinceCitiesMap in your state where you have array of cities for each province as the key and as you select the province your component will re-render as a result of setState so you can get the array of cities from that json object like this provinceCitiesMap[selProvince] this will be your cities data for the cities picker.